# iTunes Connect issue when given for testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

We are having issues with starting our internal testing of our app.
There is an exclamation mark next to the apps name in iTunes Connect and it says "Missing Compliance".
When we click "Provide export compliance information" we are provided with an option.
"Have you added or made changes to encryption features since your last submission of this app?"
To which we tick no and click "Start internal testing".
From this point we get an error message.

"Sorry, something went wrong. Try again later. If the problem persists Contact us."

Can some one please help me if they have gone thriugh this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For internal testing just add this key to your info.plist file.

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>
```

[image]

This will disable the question from being asked in iTunes connect. When you actually go to publish your application you will need to look into the compliance laws to make sure you don't need to register your encryption usage.

Comment: Ok let me check this

Comment: But for all other apps when i press no in iTunes it was going fine.

Comment: Ya, that specifically might be a bug or error of some sort. This is just a way to work around that and not have to hit yes/no.

Answer (score 5):

Another work around, instead of selecting `No`, select `Yes`.

Select `Next` and another screen will prompt you asking if you use encryption. Select `No` here and then you should be able to select `Start Internal Testing`

Comment: Thanks @amallard your workaround worked for me too. while apple fix this issue.